# What is the value of a function object in python 2.x?

Tags: python

I'm in the process of learning Python 2.x and I came across this sentence in the section [Data Model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) of the Python reference:

> Every object has an identity, a type and a value

With regards to that for the below statements, for literal integer `4`, is it of type `int`, identity `32867392L` and is it of value `4`?

If the above understanding is valid, when I declare a function, I can understand the part of getting the type and identity.

```
def a():
    pass
```

It's type is function and identity is `51025400L`. But what about value? Is it `None` since there is no return statement?

Comment: I'd say the value of a function is it's code

Answer (score 1):

It's "value" is a set of other values, which are sufficient to define exact same function.

Quoting [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html), function internal structure includes objects like:

- `__name__` - name with which this function was defined
- `func_code` - code object containing compiled function bytecode
- `func_defaults` - tuple of any default values for arguments
- `func_doc` - (same as `__doc__`)
- `func_globals` - global namespace in which this function was defined
- `func_name` - (same as `__name__`)